# Regex - change output vice versa

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I'm creating a regex password check to use it in Java application.

I wrote a code that finds all suitable passwords. How can it be changed in order to find all non-suitable passwords?

Here's code:

`(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,10}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've found all usable passwords, simply switch the boolean output of this regex.  I believe Java supports the ! operator.

Comment: I know how it could be done with boolean. But is there any way to inverse exactly regex output? Maybe there are some special symbols to inverse whole output at once etc.?